# Select rows from SQLite which contains given values

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

### Problem Description

I have an SQLite database which has `category_codes` column which can be formatted as follow:

```
1, 45 98765, 12 
545, 1, 898, 741, 78
45
87, 741
......
```

### Question

I have a string for example `545, 78`. I want to select all rows which `category_codes` columns contains `545` and `78` values.

Comment: I assume the category_codes column contains TEXT then?

Comment: @jkau yes they are text

Comment: It would be better to redesign the database structure so that each row only contains one number

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes I know, but unfortunately it contains values separated with commas :(

Comment: You can first filter by an SQL WHERE clause similar to `category_codes like '%545%' and category_codes like '%78%'` and in a second step use regular expressions in Java to remove the false positives (because `%78%` would also match `178`)

Comment: @MichaelButscher can you pleas bring an example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 4 possible places where the needle could be:

- At the beginning
- At the end
- In the middle
- Alone

If you check if one of these conditions are true, you get the row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE (
   col LIKE :param1 || ",%"
   OR col LIKE "%, " || :param1
   OR col LIKE "%, " || :param1 || ",%"
   OR col = :param1
) AND (
   col LIKE :param2 || ",%"
   OR col LIKE "%, " || :param2
   OR col LIKE "%, " || :param2 || ",%"
   OR col = :param2
)
```

Of course you have to split the string yourself. You might also create the statement dynamically, depending on how many parameters you have.

An other solution is to create a sqlite function and check the data in Java. Depending on how many rows you have, this might not be the best option.

And think about a better database schema.

Comment: And think about a better database schema <-- This.